# Use PostgreSQL to generate Unique ID for row upon insert

Tags: database, postgresql, random, concurrency, triggers

So I currently have a primary postgres database that handles multiple users from different apps. So one of the issue regarding concurrency is that when say AppOne and AppTwo want to **add** users at the same time.

Currently what is happening is AppOne will generate a random number (must be 10 digits long) and then check if the value exists in the database, if it doesn't exist then it will insert the user with that value in a column called `user_url` (used for their url).

Now as you can image, if in between the time for the generation, check, or insertion AppTwo makes a request to add a users we can have repeated unique values (it's happened). I want to solve that issue potentially using postgres triggers.

I know that I can use transactions, but I don't want to hold up the database, I'd rather it created the unique number sequence through a function and trigger on the database side, so as I scale I don't have to worry about race conditions. Once the trigger does it's thing, I can then get the newly added user with all of it's data, including the unique id.

So Ideally

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_unique_number(...) RETURNS trigger AS $$
 DECLARE
  BEGIN
   ....something here
  RETURN new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_unique_url_id BEFORE INSERT ... PROCEDURE     
set_unique_number(...);
```

it would be a function that generates the number and inserts it into the row, which would be run by a trigger of `BEFORE INSERT`. I may be wrong.

Any help/suggestions would be helpful

EDIT: I want it so that there is no sequence to the numbers. this way people could not guess the next user's url.

Thanks

Comment: Check out the use of sequence generators in PostgreSQL.  You can virtually guarantee uniqueness without the overhead and uncertainty of trying to validate in a read-consistent environment.

Answer (score 3):

9,000,000,000 is small enough number that birthday problem will guarantee that you'll start to see collisions very soon.

I think you can work around this problem while still allowing concurrent inserts by using [advisory locking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS). Your procedure might look like this (in pseudocode):

```
while (true) {
  start transaction;
  bigint new_id = floor(random())*9000000000+1000000000;
  if select pg_try_advisory_xact_lock(new_id) {
    if select not exists id from url where id=new_id {
      insert into url (id, ...) values (new_id, ...);
      commit;
      break;
    }
  }
  commit;
}
```

This procedure will never end when you'd have 9,000,000,000 rows in the database. You'd have to implement it externally, as Postgres procedures do not allow multiple transactions within a procedure. It might be possible to work around by using exceptions, but it'll be rather complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [UUID-ossp](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html) extension? It will allow you to generated UUID's from within postgres itself.

[Heres a good tutorial](https://blog.starkandwayne.com/2015/05/23/uuid-primary-keys-in-postgresql/) how to use those as primary keys even.